# getting date value from ION slider with moment when user changes the value

Tags: javascript, slider, momentjs

I have a question regarding my programming problem, I am using ION Slider (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_advanced.html) and Moment.js for date range operation. i need to set the specific date range and specific date range picker for my program.

Whenever user changes the value it should update the database. but im having a little problem here that the slider doesnt show correct format in console.log(). Please help me with this situation. My code is,

```
var startDate = moment("2014-01-05");
    var endDate = moment("2014-01-13");

    range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        grid: true,

        min: +moment(startDate).format("X"),
        max: +moment(endDate).format("X"),

        from: +moment(endDate).subtract(5, "days").format("X"),
        to: +moment(endDate).subtract(2, "days").format("X"),

        prettify: function (num) {
            return moment(num, "X").format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY");
        }
    });

    range.on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        from = $this.data("from"),
        to = $this.data("to");

        console.log(from + " - " + to);
    });
```

the console log,

```
1389113336 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389111677 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389111345 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389109686 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389108359 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389106368 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389103713 - 1389373200
jquery-... > eval (line 28)
1389102054 - 1389373200
```

it should show date in the console log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ve found the answer myself,

```
var startDate = moment("2014-01-01");
    var endDate = moment("2014-01-30");

    range.ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        grid: true,
        force_edges: true,

        min: +moment(startDate).format("X"),
        max: +moment(endDate).format("X"),

        from: +moment(endDate).subtract(5, "days").format("X"),
        to: +moment(endDate).subtract(2, "days").format("X"),

        prettify: function (num) {
            return moment(num, "X").format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY");
        }
    });


    range.on("change", function () {
            var $this = $(this), 
                from = $this.data("from"),
                to = $this.data("to");
                console.log( moment(from,"X").format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY") + " - " + moment(to,"X").format("dddd, MMM Do YYYY"))
        });

    });
```